# Programatically add a bot to list of my bots

Tags: botframework, terraform-provider-azure

Creating a bot in Azure portal or by calling `az bit create` adds the bot to the list at https://dev.botframework.com/bots

[list of bots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZbla.png)

What API is being called to add a bot to this list?

Context: I am trying to create a Azure Web App Bot with terraform provider [azurerm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm). I have managed to create most resources but I can find how to add my bot to the list above.
Terraform code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/orecht/4aa4648bac44d300450833c97385c19a)

Comment: While this does not directly answer the question above I found adding the bot this the list above was not necessary to get the web chat working. What I needed to add to my gist was a `azurerm_bot_channels_registration`. gist has been updated